# Can't use the array outside the block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Hai I am writing the code inside the block to get the placemarks of the vehicle. My problem is I stored the placemarks inside the `NSMutablearray` but i can't access the array outside the block. kindly advice me to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance. My code is below...

```
        CLLocation *someLocation=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:someLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
                NSDictionary *dictionary = [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] addressDictionary];
                addressOutlet=[dictionary valueForKey:@"Street"];
                City=[dictionary valueForKey:@"City"];
                State=[dictionary valueForKey:@"State"];
                if (addressOutlet!=NULL&&City!=NULL)
                {
                    SubTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@",addressOutlet,City,State];
                }
                else if (addressOutlet==NULL&&City!=NULL)
                {
                    SubTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",City,State];
                }
                else if (addressOutlet!=NULL&&City==NULL)
                {
                    SubTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",addressOutlet,State];
                }
                else if(addressOutlet==NULL&&City==NULL&&State!=NULL)
                {
                    SubTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",State];
                }
                else if (addressOutlet==NULL&&City==NULL&&State==NULL)
                {
                    SubTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@""];
                }
               [storeArray addObject:SubTitle];
            }
           NSLog(@"%@",storeArray);// I can access here
        }];

     NSLog(@"%@",storeArray);// Here it shows empty array
}
```

Comment: It's because the line with the NSLog printing the empty array runs before the block code is completed. If you pass the storeArray from inside the block to a function that prints it, it will run fine.

Comment: Thank you. could you please guide me with some sample code?

Comment: the completion blocks run _usually_ in different time, not sequentially after they are _defined_. therefore your code outside of the completion block runs _before_ the actual completion block _will_. (Emmett L. Brown: _"You're just not thinking fourth-dimensionally!"_)

Answer (score 3):

What you should know is the execution-flow.

In ancient *programs*, the code execution flown always from top to bottom. Anyway, this premise broken a long time ago. Modern programs are built with several components, such as function, class, and blocks(closure), and the program does not always flow top to bottom. (well, though it mostly does)

A block(closure) is one of this non-sequential program. You save a code block into a variable to execute it later. The point is, the code block is not being executed when it is being defined.

What you did here is:

1. Make an empty array.
2. Create and pass a code block which fills the array into a method.
3. Print the array using `NSLog`.

At the point of #2, the code block is not executed immediately, but will be executed when the operation will be completed. Then, the array is not yet filled when you printed it, then it prints just an empty array.

You should treat the code block defined at #2 will be executed at unknown future point of time, and you really can't control the timing. This is a bad point of asynchronous programming, and something you need to be familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to block.

The Array you collected is on asynch executed some time after the process happens.

But the outer log gets executed before the completion and collection of data and hence it returns no value and doesn't print anything

```
 [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:someLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
          //Some process collecting values in array
               [storeArray addObject:SubTitle];
            }
           NSLog(@"%@",storeArray);// I can access here
           //Do everything here after data gets populated
           [tableview reloadData];
        }];
 //Here no values exist since execuion of this happens before the inner block execution
}
```

Comment: Thank you. could you please guide me with some sample code?

Comment: I need to pass the Array value into UITableView.

Comment: So call tableview reload data inside the block...it will work

Comment: Sir I just need to get the array value and set the array value to the detailedlabel text for the tableView

Comment: @iBeginner : You will have the value achieved inside the block code.Do whatever you want from there :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler` method is executed asynchronously, and in your case the second `NSLog` get called earlier then the first one which is in completion block.

Check this: [Obj-C blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

---------EDIT-----------

You must continue your logic in completion block (i.e. when you call NSLog at first time).

```
-(void)downloadLocations:(void(^)(void))callback
{
    storeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //...
    for(int f=0;f<Vehicle_No.count;f++){
        //...
        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:someLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            //...
            NSLog(@"%@",storeArray);// I can access here

            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        }];
    }        
}

- (void)foo
{
    //...
    [self downloadLocations:^{
       //do something here with storeArray

    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. could you please guide me with some sample code?

Comment: On which line? 
Crash log?

Comment: -[MyVchicle downloadLocations]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaa3f470'

Comment: Please, look at my answer more more closely. 
Specially at the new name of method: `-(void)downloadLocations:(void(^)(void))callback`. So now you mast call your method, like I write in method `foo`.

Comment: No, you didn't. You mast call 
`[MyVchicle downloadLocations:^{// do something here...}];`

Comment: Sir I just need to get the array value and set the array value to the detailedlabel text for the tableView